# Persistent dyld: Symbol not found in Xcode 7.2

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, dyld

I've been getting this error message as an exception

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __TWPO6Darwin9MachErrorSs16RawRepresentableS_
Referenced from: /Users/Fiodor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-buqpcjbiwfvjnadievcgwbgveewn/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
Expected in: /Users/Fiodor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-buqpcjbiwfvjnadievcgwbgveewn/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
in /Users/Fiodor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-buqpcjbiwfvjnadievcgwbgveewn/Build/Products/Debug/test.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
(lldb)
```

At first I thought it was a single occurrence, because this hadn't happened to me before. But I started creating multiple Cocoa Swift projects with just the template code, and it still shows up every time.

I've already tried adding the frameworks manually to my project and changing the deployment target, but it didn't help at all.

I'm running OSX 10.11.4 Beta (15E33e), Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68).

Comment: Look at my answer and say if that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I bet that you are including a framework or some files with the ending of .dylib. With some updates from Apple they changed to .tbd

From your error code you are including libswiftFoundation.dylib.

Remove it and change it to

```
libswiftFoundation.tbd
```

Comment: I'm not very good with Xcode. How do I do it? I don't include libswiftFoundation at all and I can't find it in "Linked frameworks and libraries" -> "Add" at all. I use standard Swift Cocoa Application template for OSX in Xcode.

Comment: Is this a new project? Or when did it produce the error

Comment: I don't remember when exactly it occured for the first time, but I tried creating a few default template projects where I chaned nothing and the same problem is present.

Comment: As I mentioned, I can't add it manually, because it's not listed in frameworks list.

Comment: Did you update to a new Swift version or to a new Xcode version?

Comment: It is not good to use a Xcode beta version, this might cause the error

Comment: No, but, as I couldn't get rid of the exception, I reinstalled Xcode. Still nit working. Maybe I have to try the Xcode 7.3 Beta since I'm using the OSX Beta?

Comment: Try to remove the beta, it is always bad to use betas because there are strange errors sometimes

Comment: I'm nit using the Xcode Beta, I was just wondering if I should start using the Beta.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102103/discussion-between-anokrize-and-fiodor).